# Site is broken because counter gets an invalid number or reaches a certain number

Tags: magento2, php

After a while all websites are broken. When I restore db it works, but then it will be also broken after some time.

I found this code:

```
<ul class="sm-megamenu-hover sm_megamenu_menu sm_megamenu_menu_black" data-jsapi="on">
<!-- Category Start -->
<?php $categoryHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category'); ?>
<?php foreach($categoryHelper->getStoreCategories() as $category): ?>
<?php $category_id= $category->getId(); ?>
<?php $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$object_manager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category->getEntityId());
$testse = $object_manager->getChildrenCategories(); ?>
<?php if($testse->count()>0) { ?>
<li class="list parent-item -parent other-toggle sm_megamenu_lv1 sm_megamenu_drop parent ">
```

In this case it appears that the code is using some counter and it is possible if this counter gets an invalid number or reaches a certain number, it can cause the application to break as seems to be the case and since there are no `Apache web server` errors generated, but a `PHP` code one - it means that the application's code is causing the issue.

I have ran another restore of only the database of the site and the issue had gone away, which means that the code is calling some variable from the database that after some change, is causing the application to break, which confirms that the issue is code-related.

I have now disabled the mega menu. Maybe then the issue will stop.

Comment: What is the exact PHP error you receive when it breaks?

Comment: A developer found a javascript file that a previous developer had put on it to get access to everything. This person had hacked the sites. My new developer has fixed the issue. Problem solved